# Trouble when trying to check list with another list

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, external

One part of my program allows the user to check whether the clues they have entered are correct with the  solved version which is in an external file named solved.txt... So far I have the code shown below however it is only showing the three clue pairings at the beginning of the program which are correct, not the ones which I have added throughout the program. I think this is just something minor but I am a bit stuck on what to change.

Here is my code so far...

```
def check_clues():
    # Dictionary to hold all of the symbol/letter combos
    coded_dict = {}

    # Go through each symbol/letter combination together
    with open("words.txt") as fw, open("solved.txt") as fs:
        for fw_line, fs_line in zip(fw, fs):
            for fw_symbol, fs_letter in zip(fw_line.strip(), fs_line.strip()):
                # Add the symbol/letter combination to the dictionary
                coded_dict[fw_symbol] = fs_letter

    correct_clues = []
    with open("clues.txt") as fc:
        for fc_line in fc:
            # If the symbol is in the dictionary and the letter matches the symbol
            if fc_line[1] in coded_dict and coded_dict[fc_line[1]] == fc_line[0]:
                # Add a correct clue to your list
                correct_clues.append(fc_line.strip())

    print("You got a total of {0} correct: {1}".format(len(correct_clues), ", ".join(correct_clues)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_clues()
```

Below is a link to what is in each of the files...

**http://www.codeshare.io/vgwrC**

If needed, I will add the code for all of my program...

Comment: It would be better to just put the files into the program for the purposes of the demo. It means we can just copy the program into an interpreter and run it, which lets us see what it's doing much faster.

Comment: OK, so you want me to put whats in the files and add it to the question?

Comment: Would you be able to do it because I am unsure how to do it...

Comment: "not the ones which I have added throughout the program" On what line do you add clues?

Comment: copy the contents of the files, edit your questions  paste the contents

Comment: I am not sure.... Basically what I want to happen is after the user has entered all the clues which they think are right, they then have the option to check these with the real version.... The output should be something like they get 5 correct or 4 correct and so on... However what happens when I run it is that it keeps on saying that I have only got 3 clues right and the 3 clues which are shown are the ones which were originally at the beginning of the program, not the ones which the user has added throughout the program....

Comment: What do you mean by contents?

Comment: I don't see the part of your code that lets the user add clues throughout the program, which line do you think that happens on?

Comment: Oh that is another option in my program....

Comment: That isn't apart of the code shown in the question...

Comment: Shall I add the code for my whole program for you to gain a better understanding?